# Beamer overlay with both effects of only and onslide

Tags: beamer, overlays

I meet the following question when using Beamer:

Example1:

1st page

```
A
```

2nd page

```
B
C
```

3rd page

```
D
C

E
```

4th page

```
D

F
E
```

And I require in every page the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th lines are in the same position respectively.(e.g. A in page1 and B in page2 in the same position) How to realize such effect? Thank you for your help.

A,B,C,D,E,F are some equations or texts. If I only use `\only`, I find that page1's A will in the center of page2's BC.

---

Example2:
page1

```
A

H
```

page2

```
C
```

page3

```
D
B
```

page4

```
E
F
```

I've figured out the 2nd example:

```
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{A}
\only<2>{C}
\only<3>{D}
\only<4>{E}

\onslide<3,4>{\alt<3>{B}{F}}

\only<1>{H}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\visible` or `\invlisible` to hide content while keeping the spacing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \visible<1>{A}

        \visible<2->{\alt<2>{B}{D}}

        \visible<2,3>{C}

        \visible<4>{F}

        \visible<3->{E}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

See also section 9.3 in the [`beamer`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) class documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I update a example2, I try to use your method `\alt` to tackle the replacement of 2nd line(i.e. B,F), but I find it has one more blank line.